# Exists something like a Nonetype path?

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

In my classes I like to initiate my path variables with None. If I use `os.path` it is easy to compare with other paths. But I like more the pathlib style.

Is there a solution to do this:

```py
import os

path1 = os.path.dirname('D\\test\\file.py')
path2 = None

if path1 == path2:
    print('OK')
```

With pathlib?

My Attempt was this:

```
from pathlib import Path

test1 = Path('D/test/file.py')
test2 = Path(None)

if test1.resolve() == test2.resolve():
    print('ok')
```

But this is not working because `Path()` doesn't accept `None` and `None` hast no method `resolve()`

Comment: Do you consider your first attempt a failure because it points out that **the `if` does not end with a colon**? Because with, it seems to work as intended: `None` is not equal to the simple string `D\test`

Comment: The first works **with** column as I expected. I fixed this issue in the question. The Problem is the second part.

Comment: An empty path `Path('')` works with `resolve`. But why are you set on using `resolve`? It works without -- a `Path` path is just a simple string.

Comment: ```Path()``` is not a simple string. It returns an object of type ```pathlib.WindowsPath``` or any other distribution. Multiple methods build-in, including ```resolve()```. I don't use ```Path``` just for ```resolve```

Comment: Apologies `:)` That was based on your first attempt, not with `Path`. Hope somebody can solve it for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give yourself a sentinel whose `resolve` method returns `None` to do your checks.

Example:

```
from pathlib import Path

# You can use type to quickly create a throwaway class with a resolve method
NonePath = type('NonePath', (), {'resolve': lambda: None})

test1 = Path('D/test/file.py')
test2 = NonePath

if test1.resolve() == test2.resolve():
    print('ok')
elif test2.resolve() is None: # returning None allows you to do your check
    print('test2 is NonePath')
```

You could  go even farther with that and pull the `__dict__` from `Path` and exchange all the methods and attributes with `None` but that seems like overkill.

Disclaimer: This is probably a bad idea

```
from pathlib import Path
# this changes all methods to return None
# and sets all attributes to None
# if they aren't dunder methods or attributes
path_dict = {k: lambda: None if callable(v) else None 
             for k, v in Path.__dict__.items() 
             if not k.startswith('__')}

NonePath = type('NonePath', (), path_dict)
```

Comment: Why is the last mentioned a probalby bad idea?

Comment: I don't know `pathlib` well enough to know how every part of it works, but... There's a good chance that there's some dependency like a private method that would break other parts if it were to return `None`. Testing methods or attributes like `resolve()` that you wish to use before you use them would be a good idea.

Comment: thanks mate. Just a short edit to your awnser (I couldn't do it because the 6 Rule): Your ```else if``` should be ```elif```

Comment: lol good catch. That's a typo I consistently make from the main language I use.