# Python: How to make a pathlib Path function argument optional?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, pathlib

I pass a `Path` argument to a function:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def my_function(my_path: Path):
    pass
```

and I would like to make the argument optional.

My first naive attempt doesn't work because `Path()` (somewhat surprisingly to me) creates a `PosixPath` object for the current directory (on macOS here; `WindowsPath` on Windows):

```py
from pathlib import Path

def my_function(my_path: Path = Path()):
    if my_path:
        print(f'my_path arg:  {my_path}')
        print(f'my_path type: {type(my_path)}')
    else:
        print(f'no my_path argument; falling back to some default (or so)')

my_function()
```

output:

```
my_path arg:  .
my_path type: <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>
```

The probably obvious approach to use `None` does work:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def my_function(my_path: Path = None):
    if my_path:
        print(f'my_path arg:  {my_path}')
        print(f'my_path type: {type(my_path)}')
    else:
        print(f'no my_path argument; falling back to some default (or so)')

my_function()
```

output:

```
no my_path argument; falling back to some default (or so)
```

but that causes a `pyright` issue

```
Expression of type "None" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "Path"
  Type "None" cannot be assigned to type "Path"
```

which forces me to consider `Path` and `None` types; I think that's what [`typing.Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) is for:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing  import Union

def my_function(my_path: Union[None, Path] = None):
    if my_path:
        print(f'my_path arg:  {my_path}')
        print(f'my_path type: {type(my_path)}')
    else:
        print(f'no my_path argument; falling back to some default (or so)')

my_function()
```

output:

```
no my_path argument; falling back to some default (or so)
```

**THE PROBLEM:** I have *a lot of* functions I pass `Path` arguments to - and having to keep `None` *and* `Path` types in mind seems rather inelegant to me - and also causes all sorts of complications down the line. Therefore, I would really like something like a `NonePath` that is of type `Path` and of which I can create objects that evaluate to `False`.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63194915) SO answer (and learned about [creating new types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) in python on the way ) and figured from [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) that in order to make an object testable for truthiness, I need to give it a `__bool__()` method.

My next (still naive) attempt:

```py
from pathlib import Path

NonePath = type('NonePath', (), {'__bool__': lambda: False})

def my_function(my_path: Path = NonePath):
    if my_path:
        print(f'my_path arg:  {my_path}')
        print(f'my_path type: {type(my_path)}')
    else:
        print(f'no my_path argument; falling back to some default (or so)')

my_function()
```

output:

```
my_path arg:  <class '__main__.NonePath'>
my_path type: <class 'type'>
```

is not correct of course - I need to use a `NonePath()` object as default, not a `NonePath` type; next attempt:

```py
from pathlib import Path

NonePath = type('NonePath', (), {'__bool__': lambda: False})

def my_function(my_path: Path = NonePath()):  # <-- adding ()
    if my_path:
        print(f'my_path arg:  {my_path}')
        print(f'my_path type: {type(my_path)}')
    else:
        print(f'no my_path argument; falling back to some default (or so)')

my_function()
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in my_function
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I don't really understand the error and continuing to screw around cluelessly with this hasn't gotten me anywhere - but simply returning `False` (or should it be `None` ?) anyway seems not the right approach: Shouldn't I return `True` / `False` based on some test on one of the object's attributes ? Which ones ?

Also, shouldn't I use `Path` as the base for `NonePath` ? Didn't really get anywhere with that, either:

```py
from pathlib import Path

# NOTE: trailing comma required to make second arg a tuple
NonePath = type('NonePath', (Path,), {'__bool__': lambda: False})

def my_function(my_path: Path = NonePath()):
    if my_path:
        print(f'my_path arg:  {my_path}')
        print(f'my_path type: {type(my_path)}')
    else:
        print(f'no my_path argument; falling back to some default (or so)')
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/pathlib.py", line 960, in __new__
    self = cls._from_parts(args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/pathlib.py", line 594, in _from_parts
    drv, root, parts = self._parse_args(args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/pathlib.py", line 587, in _parse_args
    return cls._flavour.parse_parts(parts)
AttributeError: type object 'NonePath' has no attribute '_flavour'
```

Sounds to me like I need to override more `Path` methods for `NonePath`.

Well, I clearly seem to be out of my depths with python internals here. For the moment, I'll have to use what works and live with the inelegant `None` / `Path` approach.

**MY QUESTION:** Is it possible to implement a `NonePath` as explained ? How would I go about it ? Am I at least somewhat on the right track ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What wrong with using `None` if it models exactly what you're trying to do? If you don't like writing `Union[None, Path]`, do note that it can be written more simply as `Optional[Path]` or `Path | None`, and you can always shorten it further by using a type alias like `NonePath = Path | None`.

Comment: @Brian61354270: OK, now that I've learned about the various alternatives to `Union` from your comment, using `None` indeed seems a lot less inelegant. Would you mind turning your comment into an answer ?

Comment: When the path is not given, is there a reasonable default that you want to use? What behaviro do you want in this case?

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, what did you expect `Path()` to do?

Comment: I agree with your statements under "The Problem". Using `Optional` (or its variations) polutes the code with many `if` statements to check for `None`. I avoid this approach as much as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to specify `my_path` as optional:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Optional


def myfunction(my_path: Optional[Path] = None):
    if my_path is None:
        print(f'no my_path argument; falling back to some default (or so)')
        my_path = Path().resolve()
    print(f"{my_path=}")


myfunction()
print("---")
myfunction(Path("/bin"))
```

When I ran this script from the /tmp dir, I got the following output:

```
no my_path argument; falling back to some default (or so)
my_path=PosixPath('/private/tmp')
---
my_path=PosixPath('/bin')
```

The above does not cause any pyright issue

Comment: I edited your answer to include a note on the different ways to write `Optional[X]` and to add a link to the docs. Feel free to rollback if you think it doesn't align with your original intent.